# Easy to use web interface for an existing FTP server

Tags: web-apps, ftp, self-hosted, uploader

I'm a beginner when it comes to FTP clients and administration. I have a possibility to store some media files on my NAS. I have setup a FTP client on my NAS but it has no GUI. So I am using Total Commander and other tools to connect and upload media files.

My problem is, that I want to share a folder of my NAS for a small group of people, which have no idea how to use FTP. They should be able to upload files from their computers via drag and drop. Is there any FTP client software with an easy to use web interface?

I am using Windows but can setup a Linux system, if required. The software should not cost more than $50.

If possible, I like the idea to change the web interface as I like.

Answer (score 5):

Windows File Explorer [is capable of acting as a FTP client](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-access-an-ftp-server-in-windows-explorer.html). This is likely the easiest way to allow users who don't know how to use FTP to use FTP, as it acts as if it were just a regular directory.

> - Open File Explorer
> - Enter the FTP address into the address bar (e.g. `ftp://ftp.gnu.org`)
> - Enter username and password at the prompt (if required)
> - Use the folder as you would any external drive. Drag-drop will copy files.

It's not a web interface, but it's about as intuitive as you can get for a Windows user.

Comment: The question specifically asks for a web interface.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I answered the implicit question (`NAS for a small group of people, which have no idea how to use FTP`) rather than the explicit (`FTP client with an easy to use web interface`) in hope that it could be useful to the root need rather than the purposed solution.

Answer (score 3):

[MonstaFTP](http://www.monstaftp.com/) specializes in this.

Install it on any PHP5+ server (such as Apache).

Users will have the enter the server's credentials, then they can manage files.

Drag-and-drop is supported.

Free and open source, so you can modify the web interface as you like.

[image: MonstaFTP Drag-and-drop]

Comment: Would +1 multiple times if I could; answers OP's direct question, unlike my answer